# Как урезать изображение при загрузки его на проект

Tags: php, laravel

***Помогите уменьшит изображение знаю то что нужно resize() но не пойму куда его вставлять***

***controller***

```
$target_file_name = public_path().'/upload/'.Str::random(10);
$type = $_FILES["image2"]["type"];
$type = stristr($type, '/');
$type = substr($type, 1);
$response = array();
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_name.'.'.$type);
$dopysk->ydostak =basename($request=$target_file_name.'.'.$type );
```

Comment: а если ресайзить на клиенте, то будет меньше траффика :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать пакет "[Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/)":

```
composer require intervention/image
```

Пример использования:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

...

if(!empty($request->image2)){
    $image = Image::make($request->file('image2'));
    $filename = Str::random(10).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = public_path().'/upload/';
    $image->resize($image->width()/2, $image->height()/2);
    $image->move($path, $filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример ресайза картинки с помощью gd

```
$filename = "input.jpg";
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

$newwidth = $width/5;
$newheight = $height/5;

$destination = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($destination, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($destination, "output.jpg", 100);
```

Ваш

```
$target_file_name.'.'.$type
```

надо будет пропустить через этот код. Код написан под jpeg, под другие форматы картинок может понадобиться адаптация.

Также есть Imagick - его можно использовать подобных целей.